# GWT String.replaceAll handles $0 only in dev mode but not prod

Tags: java, regex, gwt

GWT Application. When I run the app in dev mode/eclipse, the replaceAll puts the match group into the replacement string.

But when I build a war and deploy to a tomcat server, the regexp matches but just puts a literal $0 in the result, instead of the match group.

The JVMs are different version ( local:6, tomcat:7 ). But I can't find out why this happens?

```
bodyText = bodyText.replaceAll("\\[\\w+ *\\w*\\]", "<span style=\"color:red;\">$0</span>");
```

Comment: Try to replace it with `\0`. Edit: And try putting `()` around it. btw, are you sure you need to backslash so much?

Comment: I would assume this code is located in client classes which get compiled into javascript. So this behavior has nothing to do with java version, but is rather consequence of regex differences in java and javascript and the way GWT compiler translates java code into javascript.

Comment: @Broxzier: I think you're right.  JavaScript uses `$&` for the whole match, not `$0`.  If you put it in a capturing group you can use `$1`, which does work in JS.

Answer (score 0):

I surrounded the regex with parens and used $1 instead to get around the issue.